# SQL Converting to HH:MM:SS with an equation - Not working Correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, type-conversion, date-conversion

I am trying to minus the sum of one column from the sum of another column in seconds, and then convert it into HH:MM:SS. The conversion however requires it to be able to go over 24 hours as this is a sum time. My conversion works on single columns with no problem so it is clearly the equation i am trying to do it in but cant figure out how to do it.

The 2 columns are Dispo & Dead both are Ints.

Here is what i have:

```
CONVERT(varchar(6), SUM([Dispo])-SUM(Dead)/3600)
+ ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), (SUM([Dispo])-SUM(Dead)% 3600) / 60), 2)
+ ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), SUM([Dispo])-SUM(Dead) % 60), 2) AS [AfterCallWork],
```

The Result it gives me is:

```
AfterCallWork   
26809:0*:0*
```

The Result i want for e.g. is:

```
AfterCallWork
35:51:09
```

(The number in the e.g. wont necessarily be the result just an example of format)

Sample Data is:

```
UniqueID | Dead | Dispo
135151   | 20   | 200
161681   | 35   | 421
516168   | 10   | 308
```

expected results for this sample is 0 hours, 14 minues and 24 seconds:

```
0:14:24
```

Dead & Dispo are seconds in a given status or mode. Unique ID is essentially a call identifier.

Comment: That is invalid standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Looks like t-sql, meaning sql server. Please edit your question to include some sample data as DDL+DML and desired result.

Comment: Desired Result was already there. Added some sample data also

Comment: Yes, it was, but it was not what you would expect to get from the sample data. This is why I've edited your question. (and to add Sql Server tags)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it -

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    UniqueID int,
    Dead int,
    Dispo int
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(135151, 20, 200),
(161681, 35, 421),
(516168, 10, 308)
```

Use a CTE to get the `SUM([Dispo])-SUM(Dead)` - This step is only to make the code more readable, you don't need to do it, but it helps:

```
;WITH CTE(NumberOfSeconds) AS
(
    SELECT SUM([Dispo])-SUM(Dead)
    FROM @T
)
```

Convert the number of seconds you got from the CTE to a string representation of `hh:mm:ss`

```
SELECT  CAST(NumberOfSeconds /3600 as varchar(6)) + ':' +
        RIGHT('0' + CAST((NumberOfSeconds % 3600) / 60 as varchar(2)), 2) + ':' +
        RIGHT('0' + CAST(NumberOfSeconds % 60 as varchar(2)), 2) As AfterCallWork
FROM CTE
```

Results:

```
AfterCallWork
0:14:24
```

[See a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/BFEG30455)